# How can I see the creation dates for my conda environments?

Tags: python, virtualenv, conda

I created four different versions of `conda virtual environments` (envs) for image processing tasks. Each env includes `GDAL` and `OpenCV`, and some subset of related libs and dependencies. I want to cull my list of image processing envs down to the most recently created one, which will have the most complete set of the libs I use. But I don't remember the order I created the envs.

Is there a way to see the creation date of individual envs or perhaps a list of creation dates for all of my conda envs?

UPDATE

Here is the output of the command suggested by @Timur Shtatland

```
$ conda env list -v -v -v | grep -v '^#' | perl -lane 'print $F[-1]' | xargs ls -lrt1d
$ miniconda3/envs/opencv2_imgproc
$ miniconda3/envs/GDAL_OSGEO_env
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Conda `history` files

Aside from file/folder dates, Conda also records the history of all environment changes in the `conda-meta/history` file relative to each environment folder, so that could also be consulted. All entries begin with a  date stamp (`==> YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS <==`), so assuming the first entry corresponds with env creation, one could do something like

```bash
#!/bin/bash

for env_hist in path/to/envs/*/conda-meta/history; do
    env_prefix=$(dirname $(dirname $env_hist))
    echo "$(head -n1 $env_hist) $env_prefix"
done | sort
```

to print something like

```bash
==> 2020-09-28 16:12:49 <== path/to/envs/pymc39
==> 2020-11-08 18:15:26 <== path/to/envs/bioc_3_12
==> 2020-11-22 17:19:08 <== path/to/envs/snakemake_5_29
==> 2021-01-23 00:08:33 <== path/to/envs/pymc3_11
==> 2021-01-23 00:12:53 <== path/to/envs/jupyter
==> 2021-03-09 22:50:38 <== path/to/envs/multiqc
==> 2021-03-24 13:20:07 <== path/to/envs/grayskull
==> 2021-04-05 23:40:01 <== path/to/envs/snakemake_6_1
```

Comment: You can get the path to your environment with the command `conda env list`.  In my install, the file of interest was found in `/home/{username}/miniconda3/envs/{env_name}/conda-meta/history`.

Answer (score 4):

Use `conda env list` to print to STDOUT the list of conda environments and the env paths. Follow this by `ls -lrt1d <env paths>`, which prints to STDOUT the paths sorted by time:

```
conda env list
# conda environments:
#
# base                  *  /Users/user_name/miniconda3
# ...
# bioperl                  /Users/user_name/miniconda3/envs/bioperl
# biopython                /Users/user_name/miniconda3/envs/biopython
# ...

ls -lrt1d env_paths
# Example:
# ls -lrt1d /Users/user_name/miniconda3/envs/bio*
```

Putting it all together:

```
conda env list | grep -v '^#' | perl -lane 'print $F[-1]' | xargs ls -lrt1d
```

Comment: On my mac, this returns a list of the envs but without any date information. Does the order of items in the list indicate creation order?

Comment: @someguyinafloppyhat No, `conda env list` returns the envs sorted ASCIIbetically. I then have to copy the paths and use them as arguments to `ls -lrt1d`, which does sort them by time in reverse.

Comment: @someguyinafloppyhat I combined everything into one command and updated the answer.

Comment: Timur: thanks for combining everything into one command. However, at least on my mac it still does not yield any date-time info.

Comment: @someguyinafloppyhat Could you post a few relevant lines from the output of `conda env list` ? Or try to increase the output verbosity, using instead `conda env list -v -v -v` (that's right, ` -v` 3 times).

Comment: I updated the original post with the results of the command from Timur Shtatland

Comment: @someguyinafloppyhat OK, I was able to reproduce and fix the issue. I think it is due to the difference in macOS `ls` (which is standard on mac) and GNU `ls` (which I used). Simply remove the `-1` (one) option to `ls`. The corrected command (tested with macOS `ls`) is: `conda env list -v -v -v | grep -v '^#' | perl -lane 'print $F[-1]' | xargs /bin/ls -lrtd`

Comment: yes I can confirm that Timur's updated command yields a list of environments with dates and times. Thanks for updating. Both your answer and @merv 's answer work equally well, though Timur's method is more succinct.